# $_SESSION not assigning cookies

Tags: php, session, cookies

Im using a login script. It was working fine until i start using PHP 5.4. It looks like it doesn't seems to register cookies after I updated my PHP version. Can someone point me out the problem or is there something else i can use instead of $_SESSION

```
session_start();
ob_start();
include('../db.php');

if(!isset($_SESSION['adminuser'])){
if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST")
{
// username and password sent from Form
$adminuser=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['adminuser']); 
$adminpassword=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['adminpassword']); 
$gpassword=md5($adminpassword); // Encrypted Password
$sql="SELECT id FROM admin WHERE adminuser='$adminuser' and adminpassword='$gpassword'";
$result=mysql_query($sql);
$count=mysql_num_rows($result);

// If result matched $username and $password, table row must be 1 row
if($count==1)
{
$_SESSION["adminuser"] = $adminuser;

header("location:index.php");
}
else
{
header("location:login.php?error=error");

}
}
ob_end_flush();
```

thanks in advance.

Comment: Adding values to `$_SESSION` will not set cookie. It'll just add it to current session.

Comment: Check settings for sessions in your php.ini. Make phpinfo() and check all settings with session. prefix

Comment: @ElonThan maybe PHPSESSID is what he means ....

Comment: WHENE you set `Session_start();` the php sets a cookie named PHPSESSIONID this cookie makes transaction between client and server by the way of session

Comment: remove all cookies then request your localhost then check of the cookie of PHPSESSIONID is set